# How to pass local variables in iteration to turbo_stream?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, hotwire-rails, turbo

In my app I have projects which have many tasks. The tasks are iterated through on the projects show page:

```
### Project#show 

 <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    <tr class="cursor-pointer">
       <td class="px-6 pr-3 py-4 w-12">

         <%= form_with(...) do |form| %>
           <div id="task_checkbox_<%= task.id %>">
              <%= render partial: "projects/partials/task_checkbox", locals: { form: form, task: task } %>
           </div>
         <% end %>

       </td>
   </tr>
<% end %>
```

The Partial however has the regarding form element which is a radio button:

```
### Partial: projects/partials/_task_checkbox.html.erb
e´
<%= form.label :done, value: false, class:"block whitespace-nowrap" do %>
<%= form.radio_button(:done, false, class:"hidden", onchange: "this.form.requestSubmit()") %>
  <p>Radio Button Label</p>
<% end %>
```

If i click the radio button within the iteration for tasks, the task switches it's state to `done: true` as expected. However the whole thing is tied to a turbo_stream:

```
### update.turbo_stream.erb -> Update action of tasks_controller

<%= turbo_stream.replace "task_checkbox" do %>
<%= render partial: "projects/partials/task_checkbox", locals: { form: form, task: task } %>
<% end %>
```

```
### tasks_controller.rb

 def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.turbo_stream
        format.html { redirect_to task_url(@task), notice: "Task was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Since the partial is within the tasks iteration and a form, i pass two local variables `form` and `task`. However, updating the task to `done: true` returns an error for the turbo_stream unit as follows:

`undefined local variable or method 'task'`

I found [this file within the turbo-rails](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo-rails/blob/main/app/models/turbo/streams/tag_builder.rb) rep, which does not really help me, since the use case is different (i font want to replace the whole iteration but one field). Variations didn't work either so far.

How do I pass local variables through a turbo stream to a partial?

Comment: can you show what you have in the update action of your tasks controller? if you have instance variables for both form and task then i suggest you use that instead in your stream.erb.

Comment: I updated the post! unfortunately i cant use instance vars since the form is relying on a local variable. I never tried to pass an instance var into an iteration though.

Comment: i am not sure but why would the form care about variable type. imo, if your @task in your `update` action is the exact task which was updated then it should work and the error should go away.

Comment: could you explain how the @task instance variable would affect the shown code? I mean the error is because of the local variables not getting passed arent they?

Comment: Ah btw. the `@tasks` (plural) is not the same instance var as the `@task` in the update action of the tasks_controller. the `@tasks` in the iteration is returning a collection of all tasks (`Task.all`).

Comment: yes. seems like the variables are not passed correctly. since you have `@task` which is the updated `task` i was emphasizing that to be passed directly to your stream. so roughly sth like:
```<%= turbo_stream.replace "task_checkbox" do %>
<%= render partial: "projects/partials/task_checkbox", locals: { form: form, task: @task } %>
<% end %>``` 
since @task is what you really need to update to. given your code snippets i can't make out as to how your `task` == `@task` which would not be true in actual.